# Mysql text to data format especially to MM:SS

Tags: mysql, format

I am wondering how to express average time formatted like "MM:SS".
 I have a table typed with text.

```
myTable1
09:37
10:17
...
```

If I changed myTable to TIME type, which returns "hour:minute:00", not "MM:SS"

```
myTable2
09:37:00
10:17:00
```

So, what I found is

```
avg(time_format(sec_to_time(round(time_to_sec(TPP)/60, 0)), '%i:%s'))
```

It returns

```
myTable3
09:37
10:17
```

my final goal is averaging those rows
When I use avg() on myTable1,3 it returns '9.5000'

as I expected it returns '09:57'

My questions came from the goal to average myTable1 to be with "MM:SS" formatted

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the hour component and not dividing by 60?

```
time_format(sec_to_time(avg(time_to_sec(concat('00:', TPP)
                                       )
                           )
                       ), '%i:%s'
           )
```

The `avg()` should also be called on the numeric value of seconds, before the conversion back to a time format.

Comment: That looks good!! I am outside now, I will be doing yours asap Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to first convert your string to time, then seconds, in order to compute the average. Then convert back to a string with the desired format :

```
TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(
    AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(TPP, '%h:%i')))
), '%h:%i')
```